# When I install GUI on Server 17.10 logon screen unresponsive

Tags: server

I wanted to install a GUI on Ubuntu Server 17.10 I used:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

However when I restarted the server and got to the login screen the mouse was very jerky and I couldn't get logged in.

What can I do to get the GUI working.

I had done this previously on 17.04 and it worked fine?

Siv